# SQL - Order by - Group by - Distinct

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so i have this code and it works ok, but iam very sure, that you guys can make it a lot better without the while loop and only in one simple query ! I tryed to make it with ORDER BY date and GROUP BY userid, but i always get the wrong date. Can you guys give me your solution for that.

Thats what i have:

```
$abfrage1 = "SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM updates WHERE city='Berlin'";
$ergebnis1 = mysql_query($abfrage1);

if($ergebnis1 == TRUE)
{
    $menge1 = mysql_num_rows($ergebnis1);
    if($menge1 != 0)
    {
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis1))
        {
            $abfrage2 = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE userid='$row1->userid' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
            $ergebnis2 = mysql_query($abfrage2);

            if($ergebnis2 == TRUE)
            {
                $menge2 = mysql_num_rows($ergebnis2);
                if($menge2 != 0)
                {
                    $row2=mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis2);

                    echo "$row2->id - $row2->userid - $row2->text - $row2->date<br>";
                }
            }           
        }       
    }
}
```

Iam looking for something like that, but as i said, always getting the wrong date:

```
SELECT * FROM updates WHERE city='Berlin' GROUP BY userid ORDER BY date
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM updates WHERE city='Berlin' ORDER BY date DESC) as temp_info GROUP BY userid
```

EDIT:
Ok ! So i want to get the last activity from all users, but only the last one.
LIMIT 1 for user, but infinity users. So i first ORDER BY date to get the last activity from that user and than i want to DISTINCT the users (OR GROUP BY), so i only get one result per user.
So i tryed Order by - Group by - Distinct but i always get the wrong date and so the wrong activity. It seems that the GROUP BY kills the ORDER BY, even when i try to use subqueries.
It seems that the GROUP BY ignores the ORDER BY date DESC.
So i get one activity per user, but it's not the last one.
GROUP BY userid just takes the first entry(id) from that user independently that i first ORDER BY date.

```
id  userid      date        text
01  01      2015-04-14      bla
02  01      2015-04-15      bla
03  02      2015-04-16      bla
04  01      2015-04-17      bla
05  02      2015-04-18      bla
06  02      2015-04-19      bla
07  02      2015-04-20      bla
08  03      2015-04-21      bla
09  01      2015-04-22      bla
10  01      2015-04-23      bla

What i want:
10  01      2015-04-23      bla
08  03      2015-04-21      bla
07  02      2015-04-20      bla

But this is what i get:
01  01      2015-04-14      bla
03  02      2015-04-16      bla
08  03      2015-04-21      bla
```

I tryed to ORDER BY date and ORDER BY id, but the GROUP BY userid do his own think.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP ! MY FINAL SOLUTION:

```
SELECT u1.* FROM updates u1 JOIN
(SELECT MAX(id) as tempid, userid FROM updates WHERE city='Berlin' GROUP BY userid)
u2 ON u1.id = u2.tempid ORDER BY u1.datum DESC
```

Comment: UR WELCOME!!!!!

Comment: (in order for us to help we have to know what the problem is -- you say the date is wrong but you never say how, what you expect, what the input is, etc.  see the faq for more information on how to ask a question that can be answered.)

Comment: Ok i edited my post so it more clear what i want !

Comment: You want an aggregate function called MAX()

Comment: THX ! And i also learnt, that i need derived tables and not subqueries. JOIN, MAX() and MIN() is the key ! THANKS !

Comment: derived table does not actually mean that -- read this to learn more -- a derived table is just the result of a query. https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/26/sql-subqueries-and-derived-tables/

Comment: also you should note that many modern sql platforms support a feature called windowing functions (it was in the SQL standard a few years back) -- it allows you to solve this problem cleaner and better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived table to get the id and date for the latest activity for each user. `JOIN` this back to your updates table to get the row related to that activity.

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM updates u1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id , userid, MAX(date) as date FROM Updates GROUP BY userid) u2
  ON u1.id = u2.id and u1.date = u2.date
```

This is an assumption based on your example but wouldn't technically getting the max `id` for each user be the same as getting the latest activity? If so you could shorten the code a bit and remove the `MAX(date)` piece.

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM updates u1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as id, userid FROM Updates GROUP BY userid) u2
  ON u1.id = u2.id
```

Comment: THX ! Will try that out !

Comment: Ok this does'nt work ! It says:
#1054 - Unknown column 'u2.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: SELECT MAX(id) as tempid

Comment: Sorry I forgot to name the columns. I have edited the post.

Comment: You helped me alot ! Thank you ! I upvoted your answer but my status is to low so you don't see my upvote !

Comment: @SQLChao read this to learn what derived table means https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/26/sql-subqueries-and-derived-tables/

Comment: @Hogan I'm confused. Is there not a derived table in the query?

Comment: @SQLChao -- sorry it was not your answer, it was the OP's interpretation of your answer.  You didn't miss use it, however most people would refer to this as a sub-query not a derived table..